# How to deal with inconclusive Hessian test for maximization of $(x+y)^2/(x^2+y^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, optimization, vector-analysis, hessian-matrix

I want to maximize the following function 
$$f(x,y)=\frac{(x+y)^2}{x^2+y^2}$$
over $\mathbb{R}$.
Equating its gradient to zero gives
$$\nabla f(x,y)=0\Rightarrow x=y$$

Then, I used Wolfram to compute its Hessian $H$, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=hessian%20of%20(x%2By)%5E2%2F(x%5E2%2By%5E2)). Substituting $x=y$ into $H$, I saw that $H_{11}=-\frac{1}{x^2}<0$ and that the determinant of $H$ is zero (see previous link). Hence, according to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test), the test is inconclusive and the point might be minimum, maximum or saddle point. But again according to Wolfram it is actually a maximum and equals 2 (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximum%20of%20(x%2By)%5E2%2F(x%5E2%2By%5E2))). How can I show this?

Comment: Polar coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: prove that $$\frac{(x+y)^2}{x^2+y^2}\le 2$$
Multiplying by $$x^2+y^2$$ we get
$$(x+y)^2\le 2(x^2+y^2)$$
Multiplying out:
$$x^2+2xy+y^2\le 2x^2+2y^2$$
subtracting $$x^2+y^2+2xy$$ on both sides:
$$0\le x^2+y^2-2xy=(x-y)^2$$ which is true.
P.s.: it is $$(x-y)^2\geq 0$$

Comment: @ Dr. Sonhard Graubner, I already knew that I need to show this but I don't know how to do it. I tried breaking $f(x,y)$ into $f(x,y)=1+2xy/(x^2+y^2)$ and repeated the same process for the second term with no luck. Can you give details on how to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

Using the idea of Lord Shark:
$$
\frac{(x + y)^2}{x^2 + y^2} =
\frac{(r\cos\theta + r\sin\theta)^2}{r^2} =
1 + 2\cos\theta\sin\theta =
1 + \sin(2\theta)\le 2
$$
with $=$ when...